# Can I see my comment list with their score

Tags: discussion

As my title - can I see the comments given by me with their score?

Of course I can track my all comments in `profile-->activity-->comments`

It will show the list of all comments given by me with timestamps. But it doesn't show the score I have got on my comments. If i have to see their score I have to open each comment given on a question or answer.

Is there another way to see the score with the comment list, just like I can see the score of posts?

Comment: You can check this in [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and here check [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166873/comments) too.

Comment: @Praveen thanks I got my answer by your link `this`

Comment: @SatishSharma I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: @Praveen i didn't see any facility on stack exchange before your comment. thanks once again. its very useful we can run query as we desire and get output. thanks a lot !!. i learn a new thing today in stack exchange :)